# post increment becomes pre increment in jar

Tags: java, jar

The first snippet is from the java class I wrote, and the second is from the decompiled jar file that contained the class. 
What I noticed is that the post increment is now pre increment, and this is probably affecting my feature.

```
if (uiType.equals("structure")) {           

        NodeList images = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (int i = 0; i < images.getLength(); i++) {
            Node img = images.item(i);
            Element imgEle = (Element) img;
            String srcUrl = imgEle.getAttribute("src");
            if (srcUrl.startsWith("image")) {
                srcUrl = appUrl+"/common/"+srcUrl;
            }else {
                continue;
            } 
            imgEle.setAttribute("src", srcUrl);
        }
```

---

```
if (str5.equals("structure"))
    {
      Object localObject3;
      Object localObject5;
      Object localObject7;
      Object localObject9;
      localObject1 = localDocument.getElementsByTagName("img");
      for (int i = 0; i < ((NodeList)localObject1).getLength(); ++i) {
        Node localNode = ((NodeList)localObject1).item(i);
        localObject3 = (Element)localNode;
        localObject5 = ((Element)localObject3).getAttribute("src");
        if (((String)localObject5).startsWith("image")) {
          localObject5 = str6 + "/common/" + ((String)localObject5);

          ((Element)localObject3).setAttribute("src", (String)localObject5);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: *"What I noticed is that the post increment is now pre increment, and this is probably affecting my feature. "* And how?

Comment: I've mentioned in a comment below. I am trying to append my appurl to the relative url of the image and it works in my local machine and not in our domain box where the jar is being used. - i.e images are not displayed. I suspect that this is not the reason. just a could be.

Comment: And what was your research result about the differences between a pre-increment and a post-increment in a for loop? And are these results the cause why you thought that this might be the problem?

Comment: I did try it on my local and there was no difference... I just wanted to clear my doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't affect your program, because the increment is "by itself." The only difference between the two expressions is the value of `i` as seen by other expressions in the same statement; since there are no other expressions (the entire statement is just the increment, `i++`), post- and pre- look the same as far as you can see them.

The reason you're seeing this is that `++i` is slightly more efficient, since it doesn't need to remember the old value of `i`. It's a very simple compiler optimization, one of the few that javac will actually perform (most optimizations are done by HotSpot at run time).

You can generally trust javac to not break your program; it's a pretty well-tested compiler, and it would be very surprising if it broke something as basic as a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't affect your code in any way.
Even though the standard idiom in a for-loop is `int i = 0;i < 10; i++`, the behaviour is identical if the last term is a preincrement.

Comment: Hmm... while the images work in my local machine, its not working in our domain box where the jar is used.To be honest, I still haven't explored other possibilities.

Comment: @stackMan10 and the images are inside the jar? Anf your loading them correctly? (using 'getResourceAsStream()')

Comment: No... I'm creating a pdf using apache fop from a html. The image src, in the html starts with "images/someImage.png"... so for the pdf to display the image, I have to add "http://myapp/common/" to the image src to display the image. Which for some reason is not working.